# How to use Double instead of Long in JsNumber in Play Framework (json4s)?

Tags: json, scala, playframework, json4s

I am using Play Framework's WS API to make requests to a certain service. The service misbehaves if we send integers instead of doubles in JSON POST requests.

Even if we want to send `{ "value" : 2 }`, it would rather accept `{ "value" : 2.0 }`.

Is there a way to to that with Play Framework's JSON API which, I believe, uses `json4s`.

From what I understands, when sending JSON value, Play Framework sends it as a string with `Content-Type : application/json` header.

If not a proper way, can there be a workaround for this problem?

Code:
(this is what my code would look like with my current approach).

```
def post(key: String, value: String): Future[(Int, String)] = {
    val body = Json.obj(
      "key" -> key,
      "value" -> number
    )

    WS.url(???).post(body).map(w => (w.status, w.body))
}
```

Comment: 'The service misbehaves' <-- Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code for how you're constructing the WS call?

Comment: @planetenkiller The problem is that the web service I'm interacting with can only accept one data type for a particular value. Since, the values can vary between integer and doubles, I've defaulted to double so even when an integer is encountered, I send a double. This works fine when I run it with HTTP Client (Postman), but need to do this from inside my Play Framework application.

Comment: @GavinSchulz I've added some example code.

Comment: Can't reproduce: 
`scala> val number: Double = 2
    number: Double = 2.0
 
    scala> Json.stringify(Json.obj("value" -> number))
    res0: String = {"value":2.0}`

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco Are you sure? Which version of Play Framework or Json4s are you using? I used the same code and it does not work like you mentioned.

Comment: @chasc Play version 2.3.9 (play doesn't use json4s)... tested it on the REPL... what version are you using?

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco I'm using 2.4.3. I'll try if it works with 2.3.9

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco Just tried it with `2.9.3`. Strange thing, gives me same (2 instead of 2.0) results.

Comment: @chasc What's the exact code you are using to test it? Can you post the simplest version that exhibits the problem?

Comment: @AlvaroCarrasco I have updated the question with the exact code of the application. Also, I tried the exact same code you pasted in the console and doubles were converted to integers upon strinfiifying.